# Import Swift class into Objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, migration

I'm trying to use the Swift class in my Object-c project. So far I have created the Objective-C  project and imported the swift class and it asked me Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?, then I hit Create Bridging Header so the productname-Bridging-Header.h file is created.

Then I changed

```
Always Search User Paths-->YES
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER-->YES
```

After that I import the swift class into my viewController.m class

Example: #import "Swiftclass.swift.h"

But it says #import "Swiftclass.swift.h" file not found

Comment: Visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098696/import-swift-class-in-objective-c-mymodule-swift-h-file-not-found

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: If you have created swift file in your project then to use it you need to import "ProjectName-swift.h" And also you should write this line in ".m files" only to avoid crytical refrences

Comment: Yes its running. I changed build settings --> Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name  into mySwift class name -swift.h

Comment: Example SwiftClass-Swift.h

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `ProjectName-Swift.h`.

If your project name contain spaces, replace them with underscores (e.g. "My Project" becomes "My_Project-Swift.h")

Like,

```
 #import "My_Project-Swift.h"
```

Try like this. it will help you.