# Import Swift Framework in Objective-C Project - Error - Unknown Type Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, carthage

I've been wrestling with this specific issue for a while now. Basically I've added a framework [BigNerdRanch CoreDataStack](https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack) using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage).

But I've been having issues of using the said framework on my Objective-C codes. My project is an Objective-C project in which I recently added Swift codes and Swift frameworks.

So far I've been able to use Swift frameworks in my Swift codes with no problems. But once I started using the said Swift frameworks on my old Obj-C, specifically AppDelegate.m, I keep getting compiler error no matter what.

From what I understand I have to import it like this:

```
#import <CoreDataStack/CoreDataStack-Swift.h>
```

In which I did on AppDelegate.m.

I also have the following setup on my project:

> Project Target Setup:

[image]

> Build Settings for Swift Compilation:

[image]

I've been seeing some answers in StackOverflow to add public to the classes. But I'm unable to do so since the imported Frameworks are self-contained and only contains Headers for me to see in the XCode project.

[image]

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292578/import-swift-class-into-objective-c/37292716#37292716

Comment: please do use this #import <YOURPROJECTNAME-Swift.h> not your framwork name

Comment: Tried the <ProjectModule-Swift.h> or "ProjectModule-Swift.h" both are not working for me. Is there a specific import I need to add in the *-Swift.h file? For your suggestions to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added a framework written in swift, if they don't enable support for `Objective C`, you can't use it in your objective c code.

However, you can create a class in swift, which will be used as a mediator between the framework and your ObjC classes.

```
@objc class coreDataStackConvertor: NSObject {

    func createStack(arg: Type) {

        // Code which uses the real CoreDataStack
    }

}
```

From you objective c classes, you can use the methods in the convertor class.

Comment: How would I know if a framework would only on Swift or not?

Comment: By their documentation in git and source code, I don't see support for objective c, all their source files are in swift, and one of their minimum requirements is swift 2.2...

Comment: I'm so ashamed. I was under the impression all along that any Swift code can run on Obj-C and neglected the fact that you need to add "@objc-ish line". Thank you very much @oren you have been of great service. Now I would upvote your answer if I had enough reputation. Once I do I'll definitely revisit this. [Bookmarked]. Thanks again.