# Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc w/ UIView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I want to build some view controllers based on Swift that can be accessed from Obj-C code, like below:

```
@objc class SUnitViewController: UIViewController {
```

But Xcode keeps telling me:

```
Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc
```

Am I doing something wrong obvious here? Or is this actually feasible? Thanks.

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32099257/988169

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful.