# mymodule-swift.h file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c-swift-bridge

This is what I have a project level. and I have the same setup using $(inherited) in targets. But now I'm getting the file not found error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this same issue [Xcode 8 with mixed Swift and Objective-c project generated "ModuleName-Swift.h" header not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39668619/2139691)

I solved just building every target with the conflicted objective-c file closed.

After that, everything is working properly again.