# Regarding Header 'RealmSwift-Swift.h' not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

I've updated my `Xcode` to the Xcode 10.0 beta version and tried to run a project with `realmswift` in it, now i'm facing an error where it says:

> Header 'RealmSwift-Swift.h' not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668619/xcode-8-with-mixed-swift-and-objective-c-project-generated-modulename-swift-h (though of course there is always a chance that Xcode 10 introduces some further complication)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I noticed this after trying out the "Conversion to Swift 4.2" button (which failed for me). When I switched to another target where I didn't run this yet, the project built without problems. And after **cleaning the project properly**, the failing target worked again.

Please note that according to the Release Notes this beta has several **"known issues" regarding cleaning**, including this one (which has the workaround for it listed, too):

[image]

So you might want to try deleting the `DerivedData` folder manually on top of cleaning in Xcode.

Comment: oh this who time I was trying xcodebuild clean,thks for help