# Compile error: Header 'ChattoAdditions-Swift.h' not found

Tags: ios, swift, chat

I use [Chatto](https://github.com/badoo/Chatto) and ChattoAdditions successfully in swift project, XCode 9.2. with Cocoa Pods.

I updated Xcode to version 9.4.1.

There was an errors in automatic generated file "module.modulemap":

**Header 'ChattoAdditions-Swift.h' not found.**

There is not 'ChattoAdditions-Swift.h' file in repository.
How to fix this error?

[image: chattoError]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689246/regarding-header-realmswift-swift-h-not-found-error

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the version of Swift for the libraries: Chatto and ChattoAdditions.

The main project has swift 3.3 version. But I can use libraries with swift 4.

Steps to fix problem:

- Choose Pods in Project navigator.
- Choose target: ChattoAdditions (Chatto)
- Change Swift Language Version to Swift 4.1
- Rebuild project (Clean & Build)

[image]