# Using "Swift into ObjectiveC" but Generated Interface Header is not found

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios10

I am struggling with the attempts to add MyClass.swift into ViewController.m

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484816/modulename-swift-h-file-not-found-in-xcode8) solution but without any success. 
The code build succeeds but the Project-Swift.h is marked as "not found", this is quite annoying and I can not find the source of the issue.

Project Build setup:

1.Project uses $(PROJECT_NAME)-Swift.h as Generated Interface Header

2.Target_One uses Project-Swift.h as Generated Interface Header

3.Target_Two uses Project-Swift.h as Generated Interface Header

Switching Defines Module to YES/NO in Project&Targets in BuildSettings makes no difference, so does Always Embed Swift Libraries

I check in /DerivedData and can see that the file is there, still xCode is really confused of this file when it builds OK but the file is marked as "not found"

Comment: Same problem here ...