# PojectName-Swift.h Not found while using Both Swift and ObjC codebase

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, bridging-header

I had a perfectly working ObjC project integrated with Apple WatchKit App with Multiple Targets. Only one of the Targets is linked with the WatchKit App.

I am moving my classes to swift and hence there are ModuleName-Swift.h files being used in my code.

Followed steps given in [ModuleName-Swift.h file not found in xcode8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484816/modulename-swift-h-file-not-found-in-xcode8) and I have ensured to add the “$(PROJECT_NAME)-Swift.h” under Projects > Build Settings > Objective-C Generated Interface header name.

[image]

But when I go to the build settings - it shows as  **`Objective-C generated interface header name`** for the project target and **`Swift_ObjC_Interface_header_name`** for WatchKitApp Target

**Error thrown by compiler :** ProjectName-Swift.h file Not found

Is this causing the error? Not sure what I am Missing.

This is how I've linked the -swift.h files in Other targets

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was:

- There were Unit test cases that were failing, disrupting further Compiling of the Project

Quick Fix:

- The ObjectiveC Classes had Unit test cases associated with it.
- Some of the Unit tests were failing due to changes to the main code base.
- I had to uncheck the the following under `Edit Schemes > Build` so that they don't Build while running the WatchKit App.

[image]

I agree I will have to update the test cases to work with the Updated app, But the issue of Watch App not working is Fixed! :)